# Rest API - PHP Notice: Trying to get property of non-object error

Tags: php, rest

I am consuming a Restful API on my PHP web page.

I am using this cURL code:

```
    <?php
function callService($service) {
    $url = "https://services.onetcenter.org/ws/" . $service;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "XXXXXX:XXXXXX");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept: application/json"));
    $json = curl_exec($ch);
    return json_decode($json);
}
$search_results = callService("online/search?keyword=architect");
$first_result_title = $search_results->occupation[0]->title;
?>
```

I then call it with the following code:

```
<?php
echo $first_result_title;
?>
```

According to web service developer this is the correct code, and works in their PHP testing environment. Yet, I receive the following PHP error:

> PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in C:\myfile.php on line 20

The code on line 20 is:

```
$first_result_title = $search_results->occupation[0]->title;
```

I am not sure what the issue is, or how to resolve?
I have checked on the server, and php.ini and allow_url_fopen is "On" and cURL support is enabled.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: what does `print_r($search_results)` give you?  Are you sure you are retrieving valid json?  Try printing it out and running it through a validator.

Comment: Gives me: "PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in C:\myfile.php on line 20",
with line 20 being `$first_result_title = $search_results->occupation[0]->title;`

Comment: Check contents of `$json` before you return it - is it valid json? Are you getting a cURL error?

Comment: To try to complete the check @IvanIvan suggested, should I use `fetch()`? If so, how can I use it in the code above?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `var_dump($search_results)` or `print_r($search_results)` to check the data coming back to you is both valid and correct format.

The error indicates either `$search_results` or `$search_results->occupation[0]` is not an object. Without seeing the data returned, it's hard to know which case.

My guess is you should actually want first index `[0]` of `$search_results` and not `$search_results->occupation`, like:

`$first_result_title = $search_results[0]->occupation->title;`

If in fact you expect `$search_results` to be an object, AND its property `occupation[0]` to also be an object, you can trap the error with checks like:

```
if( is_object( $search_results ) ){
    /* $search_results is an object */
    if( isset( $search_results->occupation[0] ) && is_object( $search_results->occupation[0] ) ){
        /* $search_results is an object AND $search_results->occupation[0] is an object */
        $first_result_title = $search_results->occupation[0]->title;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to substitute the line:
    `$first_result_title = $search_results->occupation[0]->title;`

with:

   `$first_result_title = $search_results[0]->occupation->title;`

and received the error:
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\ConsultaPedia\onet.php on line 21

Comment: At: https://services.onetcenter.org/ws/online/search?keyword=architect
Use my credentials, output:
`{"keyword" : "architect","start" : 1,"end" : 20,"total" : 66,"link" : [
{
         "href" : "https://services.onetcenter.org/ws/online/search?keyword=architect&start=21&end=40",
         "rel" : "next"
}
],
"occupation" : [
{
"href" : "https://services.onetcenter.org/ws/online/occupations/17-1011.00/",
"relevance_score" : 100,
"code" : "17-1011.00",
"title" : "Architects, Except Landscape and Naval",
"tags" : {
   "bright_outlook" : false,
    "green" : true
}
}
 ...
]
}`

Comment: I then tried to use:
`if( is_object( $search_results ) ){
    /* $search_results is an object */
    if( isset( $search_results->occupation[0] ) && is_object( $search_results->occupation[0] ) ){
        /* $search_results is an object AND $search_results->occupation[0] is an object */
        $first_result_title = $search_results->occupation[0]->title;
    }
}`

The PHP error I now receive is:
"PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: first_result_title in C:\myfile.php on line 36",
with line 36 being:

`echo $first_result_title;`

Comment: As I mentioned in my original post, the web services API provider said that my code did work in their PHP testing environment. I also heard back from them again, and they said "You may need to adjust your firewall or your PHP installation to allow PHP to connect to the Web Services site."

As in my post, I checked my PHP.ini and found that:
`allow_url_fopen is "On"`

and

`cURL support is "enabled"`

not sure what to do from here ...
If this is code or PHP issue.
I am sorry for my confusion.

Comment: Per @ivanivan and @Patrick I tried `print_r($search_results)` and `var_dump($search_results)` with the same result: "PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in C:\myfile.php on line 20"
with line 20 being `$first_result_title = $search_results->occupation[0]->title;`

Comment: @Ralph_J can you put `var_dump( $search_results ) die();` above line 20?